# Как исправить Code Style в IDE Rider?

Tags: rider

Всем привет. В `IDE Rider` столкнулся с такой проблемой: по код стайлу `Unity`, сериализованные приватные поля должны именоваться без нижнего подчёркивания.

[image: **]

Чтобы исправить это, я залез в `Settings\Editor\Code style\C#`. Однако среди предложенных настроек, нет такой, которая относилась бы к Serialize Field. Что можно сделать? Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: скриншот Rider'а? если это был бы нормальный редактор, вим или эмакс - там так можно было. А в этом случае это почти невозможно

Comment: @KoVadim, почему невозможно? Эта IDE не позволяет менять код стайл относительно Unity?

Comment: я о том, что настройки IDE приложить текстом немного сложновато

Comment: @SdxSdySdz "сериализованные приватные поля" - это особенность юнити, но не C#. Поэтому, подбирайте подходящее приватное поле

Comment: хотя лучше обратится в компанию JetBrains для таких вопросов (тут они не отвечают на вопросы совсем. Видимо им не интересна русскоязычная аудитория).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым. Спасибо каналу `Emerald Powder` и всем, кто комментировал мой вопрос. `Settings\Languages&Frameworks\Unity Engine`. Здесь есть раздел связанный с `SerializeField`, где можно указать значение параметра `Prefix`